# The SQL statement is not executed inside the transaction

Tags: rust, surrealdb

The example of the `transaction` method on the [doc.rs](https://docs.rs/surrealdb/1.0.0-beta.8/surrealdb/struct.Datastore.html#method.transaction) site just shows how to begin and end a transaction, so I think I should put every SQL execution inside these. Example:

```rust
let mut transaction = datastore.transaction(true, false).await?;

let sql = "CREATE task SET title = $title, due_date = $due_date, create_at = time::now();";

let data: BTreeMap<String, Value> = [
    ("title".into(), task.title.into()),
    ("due_date".into(), task.due_date.into()),
].into();

let res = datastore.execute(sql, &session, Some(data), false).await?;

transaction.commit().await?;

debug!("{:?}", res);
```

But the console only shows the following debug message from `surrealdb`: `Executing: CREATE task SET title = $title, due_date = $due_date, create_at = time::now()`. The transaction is never complete (commit).

When I get rid of the transaction, the SQL statement is executed normally and the console shows the value of `res`.

What is the right way to use `Transaction`?

Comment: Maybe you need `transaction.execute()` instead of `datastore.execute()` ?

Comment: I don't think so, because according to the documentation, there is no `execute` method in `Transaction` struct.

Comment: It appears that is because the database adapter does not support arbitrary SQL within a transaction.